# QT C++ Compiling on Linux Terminal?

Tags: c++

I am using the terminal and gedit editor to learn QT C++. Do not mind my approach of programming, I do not like to depend on IDE's, but plain text editors. However I seem to be having some issues compiling. I created a basic simple snippet, then after saving as a .cpp extension file I type the command lines;

> ```
>  qmake -project
>  qmake
>  make
>  qmake main.cpp
> ```

All this is being done in a directory folder on my desktop called "qt". I try to run the file with:

> ```
> qmake main.cpp
> ```

and all it shows is: Unknown test function: int main.
I check the error and the int main looks fine. The int main contains two arguments an int argc, and a char *argv[] which is passed to the QApplication() function parameters in the local scope. Obviously I am doing something wrong and cannot seem to figure out what.

Also as I mentioned above about using a .cpp extension, I also tried replacing the .cpp with .pro that also did not seem to work out, it displayed the same exact errors.

Comment: .cpp is code file, .pro is the project file. You do not depend on IDE, but the C-library. The IDE is useful because there are a lot of commands to compile and link the code in executable. Better use Qt creator to see how it is calling compilation and linking of the code in the logs, then you can rebuild from terminal with the commands and values you like.

Comment: qmake foo.cpp is wrong, you must run qmake on a .pro file, which can be generated via `qmake -project`.

Comment: It worked Frank Osterfeld, thank you! Finally :)